# Perl: how to compare two files?

Tags: perl

I am trying to make script in perl which compares two text files. The differences bwteen the files should be printed out to file error.txt, together with the line number.

Example:

File 1:

```
Figure 1.
Somatotropes are organized into.
Figure 2.
Comparing two xml files organized into.
Figure 3.
Somatotropes presentation of GH1,
```

File 2:

```
Figure 1.
children with acquired organized into.
Figure 2.
Severe anterior hypoplasia,
Figure 3.
Somatotropes presentation of GH1,
```

Output required in errr.txt:

```
Error:lineno:2 please check mismatch<br>
Error:lineno:4 please check mismatch<br>
```

This is my code so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Diff;

my $file1 = 'file1.txt';
my $file2 = 'file2.txt';
my $error = 'error.txt';

open(my $in1, '<', $file1) or die "Cannot open file '$file1' for reading: $!";
open(my $in2, '<', $file2) or die "Cannot open file '$file2' for reading: $!";
open(my $out, '>', $error) or die "Cannot open file '$error' for writing: $!";

my $lineno = 1;

while (my $line1 = <$in1>)
{
    my $line2 = <$in2>;

    printf $out "Error:lineno:%d please check mismatch\n", $lineno
        unless $line1 eq $line2;

    ++$lineno;
}

close $out or die "Cannot close file '$error': $!";
close $in2 or die "Cannot close file '$file2': $!";
close $in1 or die "Cannot close file '$file1': $!";
# the logic might be it matches line by line and the whatever mismatch found grab
# the position like line no. and print it in error.txt

my $diff  = diff "file1.txt", "file2.txt";

print $out $diff;
close $out or die "Cannot close file '$error': $!";
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Posting requirements and hoping someone will do your script for you wont get you very far on SO.

Comment: Xpost at Perlmonks http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1098577

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
#!/sur/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,"file1.txt");
my @file1 = <FILE>;
close FILE;
open(FILE,"file2.txt");
my @file2 = <FILE>;
close FILE;

my @errors = ();

for(my $line = 0; $line < scalar(@file1); $line++){
    if($file1[$line] ne $file2[$line]){
        push(@errors, "Error:lineno:".($line+1));
    }
}


open(ERROR,">","error.txt");
foreach(@errors){
    print ERROR $_."\n";
}
close ERROR;
```

First it open files and put them in arrays, then in a loop, it compare each line and if they are different push a message in the error array. At the end it put errors in your error file.

The code will fail on different size files, I let you implement this fonctions, and error statement.

Answer (score 0):

What *type* of diff are you attempting? Are you assuming that the two files have the same number of lines? In a true diff, you could assume that lines might not always *line up*. Let's look a these two files:

### File #1

```
Line #1
Line #2
FOOBAR!
Line #3
Line #4
```

### File #2

```
Line #1
FOOBAR!
Line #2
Line #3
Line #4
```

We look at this and say "In file #1, there's an added line `FOOBAR` between `Line #1` and `Line #2`. In file #2, this line is between `Line #1` and `Line #2`. In a diff program, it would say these files are pretty much identical except for that `FOOBAR` line.

However, if I did a line-by-line comparison, I would find all of the lines different except for that first line.

In your program, you do a line-by-line difference and it's pretty good. You do a lot of more modern syntax, you use `strict` and `warnings`. If I was writing it, I would do my loop a bit differently. I'd probably use an infinite loop and break out of it when I run out of lines from either file:

```
for (;;) {
    my $line1 = <$in1>;
    my $line2 = <$in2>;
    if    ( not $line1 and $line2 ) {
        say STDERR "ERROR: File #1 is shorter than File #2";
        last;
    }
    elsif ( $line1 and not $line2 ) {
        say STDERR "ERROR: File #2 is shorter than File #1";
        last;
    elsif ( not $line1 and not $line2 ) {
        say "Both files are the same length";
        last
    }
    chomp $line1;
    chomp $line2;
    ...   # Compare the lines, etc.
}
```

My reasoning would be that you don't know which file will end first, and that looping for each line in one file is misleading. You're reading in *two* files until one of them run out of lines. (I would also use `say` which I like much better than `print` and `autodie` since you're just dying anyway if the files can't be opened.

You already are using `Text::Diff` which will do a file comparison for you and a bit more thoroughly than a simple line-by-line. This is why we use Perl modules. Good modules are tested in a wider arena and have found all of the various exceptions and other difficulties that make programming so difficult. Anticipating *exceptions* is what makes programming so difficult.

I would use `Text::Diff` and play around with it and its configuration. I have never used it. Howeverr, it might be possible to use its output (which can be captured), and use that to get the output you desire.